# NetBeans Platform (RCP) application installer, set expiry date?

Tags: windows-installer, rcp, netbeans-platform

Is it possible to set an expiry date for an application installer (windows - exe) that the NetBeans Platform generates? For example, I want the installer to be unusable after 30 days of the day it was created.

Answer (score 2):

you can change installer wizard.

Open project

```
\program files\NetBeans{yourversion}\harness\nbi\stub\ext\components\products\HelloWorld
```

Jirka